# Create One string from elements in an Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, react-native

I am trying to create ONE string from an array of objects `family` and have them separated by commas except for the last element `Mary`

```
const family = [
{Person: {
name: John
}}, {Person: {
name: Mike
}}, {Person: {
name: Link
}}
, {Person: {
name: Mary
}}];
```

I want the string to be like this

```
"John, Mike, Link or Mary"
```

I tried using `family.toString()` but that gives me `"John, Mike, Link, Mary"` and doesn't allow me to replace "," with an "OR"

Comment: That's not a valid structure and is not an array. You posted an object with duplicate keys which can't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pop()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) to get (and remove) the last name. Then use [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to add the rest.

Thx to [@charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993851/create-one-string-from-elements-in-an-array-of-objects/66994115#comment118420559_66994115) for suggesting a check on the number of names to prevent something like: `and John`.

```js
const family = [
  { Person: { name: "John" } },
  { Person: { name: "Mike" } },
  { Person: { name: "Link" } },
  { Person: { name: "Mary" } }
];

// Get all the names
const names = family.map((x) => x.Person.name);

// Get result based on number of names
let result = '';
if (names.length === 1) {

    // Just show the single name
    result = names[0];
} else {
  
    // Get last name
    const lastName = names.pop();
    
    // Create result 
    result = names.join(', ') + ' and ' + lastName;
}
    
// Show output
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Might want to check array length is greater than one so you don't end up with just `"and John"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a super-elogant option.  Best bet is something like:

```
function joinWord(arr, sep, finalsep) {
    return arr.slice(0,-1).join(sep) + finalsep + arr[arr.length-1];
}
```

and then

```
joinWord(family.map(x=>x.person.name), ', ', ' or ');
```

You could make the invocation a little nicer at the cost of performance and modularity with:

```
Array.prototype.joinWord = function joinWord(sep, finalsep) {
    return this.slice(0,-1).join(sep) + finalsep + this[this.length-1];
}

family.map(x=>x.person.name).joinWord(', ', ' or ')
```

But this is only a good idea if this is going to come up a lot within your program and your program is never going to be a part of something bigger.  It effects every array.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
let sp = ' or ';
family.map(x => x.Person.name)
  .reduceRight(
    (x,y) => {
      const r = sp + y + x;
      sp = ', ';
      return r;
}, '')
.replace(', ', '');
```

Hope, this question was for the school homework :)